# .htaccess redirect url for removing article id

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect the following URLs:

**From**: www.example.com/article/?id=13
**TO**: www.example.com/article/article_name

And I have following code but it's not working :

RewriteEngine on
Redirect permanent /article/?id=13 http://www.example.com/article/article_name

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you give this as an example or do you actually want ?id=13 to redirect to /article/article_name?

Comment: it's a question.
I want to do a redirect, but it does not work

Comment: You didn't answer what I asked. I ask again:  
Did you give this as an example or do you actually want ?id=13 to redirect to /article/article_name?

Comment: I want want ?id=13 to redirect to /article/article_name

Comment: Ok, and does what you tried not work?

Comment: I add this in my htaccess file :  RewriteEngine on
Redirect permanent /article/?id=13 http://www.example.com/article/article_name but it's not working